# Why would SSRS allow access some times, but not others?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS server set up to use basic authentication - using a username and password. When I visit the web management interface (https://alpha.myserver.com/Reports) I get a username/password dialog, enter the username and password that I set up, and the system gives me access. Likewise, if I visit the web services URL (https://alpha.myserver.com/reportservice) I get the same login dialog, and then the system will give me access.

Now what is strange is I am embedding a report viewer control into an MVC app. That app has configured credentials that get sent along with requests. The app uses the web service URL for some things (get the list of reports, folders, etc.) and the 'display' URLs for displaying reports.

When I run the application locally on my dev machine, configured to talk to the remote SSRS server, everything works fine. Yesterday I did my first deployment of the app to a test server and I am getting a '401 not authorized' response code when I make the web services call to list the reports. I don't understand why in same cases the credentials work and in other cases they don't. I have double and triple-checked that I am using the same domain, username, and password in each case.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS has many levels of authentication:

1. Account hosting the service
2. Your connection string for the 'Data Source'
3. Credentials for accessing the web service
4. Credentials for the item level level permissions at the folder and item level(datasource, dataset, report, etc.)

If you are adding yet another layer to this like a WCF service or something else it could be credentials related to that service not running on the domain account it is expecting.  SSRS is very very very picky about everything being in order for every level.  Too much so I would say.  If you can run a code from one server or dev box and not another I would guess that a service or account is not the same access level from the machine.  Can you get on the machine getting the restriction error, log on with that account, try to get to the URL of the report?

I would also try to have the Data Sources use a connection string embedded in them.  Unless Security is an issue where you want the user to be prompted for extra security, you may set security on the individual items yet have the data source be configured for automatic authentication.  In the designer click on datasource and choose 'credentials stored in secure server' to perform this.